# MySQL having id equals column alias

Tags: mysql

I am looking to select all conversations from a table of messages that a user is involved in. This query works for that:

```
select distinct message_conversationID from messages where message_userID = 2
```

However, I then want to in turn extract all the titles of the conversations (from another table) given the foreign key message_conversationID. I tried this:

```
select conversation_titles from conversations having conversation_id =
(select distinct message_conversationID as temp from messages where message_userID = 2)
```

But, it appears that I can't validate having id equals with multiple rows of data. How else could I extract all the titles with an id in an alias column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to have distinct conversation_title, you can user either `IN query` which matches with your existing query or `JOIN query`(recommended)

With `IN query`, your query should be like this :

```
select distinct conversation_titles from conversations where conversation_id IN
(select message_conversationID from messages where message_userID = 2)
```

With `JOIN query`, you can do similar operation :

```
select distinct conversation_titles from conversations c inner join 
    messages m on c.conversation_id = m.message_conversationID
where m.message_userID = 2
```

I would recommend second query to use in your case as it's more efficient than first query.